# Center div within div with respect to the page

Tags: css, html, styles, center

I know how to center a div layer with respect to it's wrapper or parent container, but what about When I have a div inside of a div inside of the page body. How do I center the smallest div with respect to the body?

```
<div id="1" style="width: 100%">
<div id="2" style="width: 22.5%; height: 1000000000px; margin-left: 12%;">
<div id="3" style="position: absolute;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

In the above example, How can I center div with id="3" in respect to div with id="1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#1` must be `position: absolute`, `#3` set `left: 50%` and offset half the width to the left

```
#d1 {
    position: absolute;
}

#d3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2cUK/3/) for playing.

I have moved the inline styles to the CSS panel and changed the `id`s to `d1`, `d2` and `d3` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

set `marging:0 auto` for div id=3

Comment: That just centers it inside div id=2. How do I center it inside div id=1?

Answer (score -1):

```
div#2 {
  position: relative;
}
div#3{
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

This will center the `div#3` not only horisontaly but vertically to div#2, if you are asking that. And keep in mind you can't have digits for id.

If you want to center `div#3` to `div#1` ... you just have to move the `position:relative` style from `div#2` to `div#1` .

Answer (score -1):

If you want it positioned exactly in the screen's center, you need to enclose ID#3 inside 2 divs, one that takes care of vertical alignment, and the other takes care of horizontal alignment:

```
<div id="vertical">
    <div id="horizontal">
        <div id="3" style="position: absolute;">
    </div>
</div>
```

More details are here: [dead-center](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html)